# Using 3ga and 3gp with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, conversion, 3gp

I have sometimes converted .3gp files from my Android voice recorder into .mp3, easy as pie - sometimes I combine image(s) and create videos from these recordins for Youtube, but when I try to convert .mp4 videos into .3gp, ffmpeg complains that this being unsuitable output format.

I have not found good documentation on this, as I rely heavily on ffmpeg for various conversions. I've noticed that some people use .3gp as container for videos as well as for audio - but frankly find no good documentation on this.

Good pointers appreciated.

Comment: What command are you issuing?

Comment: just basic "ffmpeg -i file.3gp file.mp4